# TNS:Protocol Adapter Error

Tags: oracle, windows-7, oracle11g, windows-8.1

I am attempting to connect to an Oracle 11.2.0.2 64 bit database from a Win 7 and Win 8.1 machine with the Oracle 11.2.0.4 32 bit client.  I can successfully ping the server and TNSPing the listener on both machines.  But when I try to log into SQLPLus using system and my password I receive ORA-12560 TNS:Protocol Adapter Error.  I can log into SQLPlus on the server.  Any ideas?  DB has been restarted as well as the listener.  ORACLE_SID is set.  I'm stuck...

Comment: How are you connecting - what is the full command you're using, including the connect string? If you're using a TNS alias then how is that defined in the tnsnames.ora file on your PC? And what was your tnsping command? (Connecting as system remotely needs additional steps, and you probably shouldn't be connecting as a built-in user anyway; but you wouldn't get an adapter error because of that).

Comment: TNS ping command is tnsping abcd.  abcd is the alias I have it listed as in the TNS names.  Unfortunately connecting as System is required.  Also if I connect to sqlplus using "system@abcd" in both win7 and win8.1 environments, it works.  In the past in other environments "@abcd" has not been needed to connect.  I am not sure why it is required now.  Is there a way around this as using "@abcd" will not work for our scenario.

Comment: You've lost me... "if I connect to sqlplus using "system@abcd" ... it works", but the question says it doesn't work. Please edit the question show exactly what does and does not work, with the full error message you get when it doesn't.

Comment: Logging into SQLPus works when logging in using system@abcd.  Logging into SQLPus does not work when using system.  This was just discovered or I would have posted in the question.  In the past(on a different machine) I have been able to log into SQLPlus using system without specifying the alias.  I am not sure why I cannot do this now.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following what you're seeing, it sounds like you just want to set [the `LOCAL` enviroment variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#i1052303) on your Windows boxes to the TNS alias; then you don't have to supply that as you try to connect.

This is with the 12c instant client but the effect is the same with the 11g client. Specifying an alias as the connect strings works (the ORA-01017 is still coming from the DB):

```
c:\Program Files\instantclient_12_1>sqlplus -l x/y@abcd

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Feb 23 17:12:34 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Connecting without the alias gets your ORA-12560:

```
c:\Program Files\instantclient_12_1>sqlplus -l x/y

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Feb 23 17:11:58 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

But if I set `LOCAL` then I can connect as if I had specified the alias:

```
c:\Program Files\instantclient_12_1>set LOCAL=abcd

c:\Program Files\instantclient_12_1>sqlplus -l x/y

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Feb 23 17:14:23 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

You don't need to have `ORACLE_SID` set as that is only used for bequeath connections where the client and server are on the same box.